# How do you plot n number of shapes in matplotlib 3d plot given a list of shapes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

within my list i have 30 data points of straight lines. i have been trying to plot those data points in matplotlib 3d plot, but only 19 lines get plotted instead of 30. Can someone show me how to overcome this 'bug' or error.

Here is my code.

```
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    #we have data points of 30 lines in this list
    lines = [
                {'x_points': [0, 5], 'y_points': [0, 0], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -4.9499617261077775], 'y_points': [0, 0.705605350084669], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, 4.800848435972757], 'y_points': [0, -1.3970877906623964], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -4.555644678256036], 'y_points': [0, 2.0606070866318644], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, 4.2192582820728255], 'y_points': [0, -2.6828826938872803], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -3.798422125273466], 'y_points': [0, 3.2514595735197154], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, 3.3015593738090168], 'y_points': [0, -3.7549574832764514], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -2.738614889457331], 'y_points': [0, 4.183298756632451], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, 2.120856180336052], 'y_points': [0, -4.527910010405504], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -1.4606478782397059], 'y_points': [0, 4.781893743674554], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, 0.7712042567067965], 'y_points': [0, -4.940166393395806], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -0.0663247432442751], 'y_points': [0, 4.999560083490704], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -0.6398822804855263], 'y_points': [0, -4.958886030866271], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, 1.3332818622914424], 'y_points': [0, 4.818958339276722], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -1.999995394897044], 'y_points': [0, -4.582577704784788], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, 2.6266784005613966], 'y_points': [0, 4.254475358963103], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -4.582642063790785], 'y_points': [0, -1.9998479230119806], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, 4.819001242809779], 'y_points': [0, 1.3331267838423373], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -4.958906620198911], 'y_points': [0, -0.6397226994154757], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, 4.999557946521049], 'y_points': [0, -0.06648563287072048], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -4.940141572895973], 'y_points': [0, 0.7713632346339236], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, 4.78184673643453], 'y_points': [0, -1.4608017624751262], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -4.527841757289726], 'y_points': [0, 2.1210018908392057], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, 4.183210623748224], 'y_points': [0, -2.7387495097872665], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -3.754851234630662], 'y_points': [0, 3.3016802094982785], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, 3.2513373357119426], 'y_points': [0, -3.798526757758271], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -2.6827469135450817], 'y_points': [0, 4.21934461710161], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, 2.0604604814408307], 'y_points': [0, -4.5557109878064725], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, -1.3969332949707383], 'y_points': [0, 4.800893392838691], 'z_points': [3, 3]}, 
                {'x_points': [0, 0.7054460561715479], 'y_points': [0, -4.949984430463596], 'z_points': [3, 3]}
            ]

    print(len(lines))

    plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
    ax.set_ylim([-5,5]) #Sets the y axis Range
    ax.set_xlim([-5,5]) #Sets the x axis Range
    ax.set_zlim([0, 6]) #Sets the z axis Range

    for line in lines:
        x_cor = line['x_points']
        y_cor = line['y_points']
        z_cor = line['z_points']

        ax.plot3D(x_cor, y_cor, z_cor, lw=1, color = 'black')

    ax.set_xlabel('x') #For labeling our axes
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('z')
    # Customize the view angle so it's easier to see that the lines lie
    # on the x,y plane
    ax.view_init(elev=90., azim=270)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Some of your lines have similar directions. [If you zoom in, you see these pairs.](https://imgur.com/dN3qvqU)

Comment: @Mr.T Thanks for that observation. i will make the necessary changes to make them visible.